# Objects/classes/lists Python

Tags: python, list, class, object

I am confused about classes in python. I don't want anyone to write down raw code but suggest methods of doing it. Right now I have the following code...

```
def main():
    lst = []
    filename = 'yob' + input('Enter year: ') + '.txt'
    for line in open(filename):
        line = line.strip()
        lst.append(line.split(',')
```

What this code does is have a input for a file based on a year. The program is placed in a folder with a bunch of text files that have different years to them. Then, I made a class...

```
class Names():
    __slots__ = ('Name', 'Gender', 'Occurences')
```

This class just defines what objects I should make. The goal of the project is to build objects and create lists based off these objects. My main function returns a list containing several elements that look like the following:

`[[jon, M, 190203], ...]`

These elements have a name in `lst[0]`, a gender `M` or `F` in `[1]` and a occurence in `[3]`. I'm trying to find the top 20 Male and Female candidates and print them out.

Goal-
There should be a function which creates a name entry, i.e. mkEntry. It should be 
passed the appropriate information, build a new object, populate the ﬁelds, and return 
it.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to populate objects and produce a list with the top 20 M and top 20 F occurences.

Comment: That's not a question.  Exactly what about the task are you having problems with?

Comment: I don't really know how to assign objects in classes. Would it work if I create a def __init__(): function with the slots and initialize each slot. Then I would append a list with each of these objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is a handy container class to hold your data in, I suggest using the `namedtuple` type factory from the [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) module, which is designed for exactly this. You should probably also use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module to handle reading your file. Python comes with "batteries included", so learn to use the standard library!

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv

Person = namedtuple('Person', ('name', 'gender', 'occurences')) # create our type

def main():
    filename = 'yob' + input('Enter year: ') + '.txt'
    with open(filename, newlines="") as f: # parameters differ a bit in Python 2
        reader = csv.reader(f) # the reader handles splitting the lines for you
        lst = [Person(*row) for row in reader]
```

Note: If you're using Python 2, the `csv` module needs you to `open` the file in binary mode (with a second argument of `'rb'`) rather than using the `newlines` parameter.

If your file had just the single person you used in your example output, you' get a list with one `Person` object:

```
>>> print(lst)    
[Person(name='jon', gender='M', occurences=190203)]
```

You can access the various values either by index (like a `list` or `tuple`) or by attribute name (like a custom object):

```
>>> jon = lst[0]
>>> print(jon[0])
jon
>>> print(jon.gender)
M
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class, add an `__init__` method, like this:

```
def __init__(self, name, gender, occurrences):
    self.Name = name
    # etc.
```

Now you don't need a separate "make" method; just call the class itself as a constructor:

```
myname = Names(lst[0], etc.)
```

And that's all there is to it.

If you really want an mkEntry function anyway, it'll just be a one-liner: `return Names(etc.)`

Answer (score 0):

I know you said not to write out the code but it's just easier to explain it this way. You don't need to use slots - they're for a specialised optimisation purpose (and if you don't know what it is, you don't need it).

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, gender, occurrences):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.occurrences = occurrences


def main():
    # read in the csv to create a list of Person objects
    people = []
    filename = 'yob' + input('Enter year: ') + '.txt'
    for line in open(filename):
        line = line.strip()
        fields = line.split(',')
        p = Person(fields[0], fields[1], int(fields[2]))
        people.append(p)

    # split into genders
    p_m = [p for p in people if p.gender == 'M']
    p_f = [p for p in people if p.gender == 'F']

    # sort each by occurrences descending
    p_m = sorted(p_m, key=lambda x: -x.occurrences)
    p_f = sorted(p_f, key=lambda x: -x.occurrences)

    # print out the first 20 of each
    for p in p_m[:20]:
        print p.name, p.gender, p.occurrences
    for p in p_f[:20]:
        print p.name, p.gender, p.occurrences

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've used a couple of features here that might look a little scary, but they're easy enough once you get used to them (and you'll see them all over python code). List comprehensions give us an easy way of filtering our list of people into genders. lambda gives you an anonymous function. The [:20] syntax says, give me the first 20 elements of this list - refer to list slicing.

Your case is quite simple and you probably don't even really need the class / objects but it should give you an idea of how you use them. There's also a csv reading library in python that will help you out if the csvs are more complex (quoted fields etc).